# can we use order by after where clause in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to sort the record on milestone id coloumn but it is throwing error at order by in subquery giving error as "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetALLStudyCodedtls]
(
    @StudyCodeId VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS

BEGIN

    SELECT X.[IsActive]
           --scd.[StudyCodeId]
           ,
           X.[StudyCode],
           X.[ProductName],
           X.[TherapyName],
           X.[Dosage],
           X.[StudyType],
           X.[Condition],
           X.[CountryName],
           X.[CRO],
           X.[Design],
           X.[DesignTag],
           X.[RnD ProjManager],
           X.[Project Manager],
           X.[IPDFillingTimeline],
           X.[Comments],
           X.[MileStoneId],
           X.[Milestone],
           X.[Category],
           X.[BaseLineDate],
           X.[ActualDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT sc.IsActive
               --scd.[StudyCodeId]
               ,
               scd.[StudyCode],
               pm.ProductName,
               tm.TherapyName,
               dm.Dosage,
               stm.StudyType,
               com.Condition,
               cn.CountryName,
               crm.CRO,
               dsm.Design,
               dtm.DesignTag,
               ud.[user_name] AS 'RnD ProjManager',
               udd.[user_name] AS 'Project Manager',
               scd.[IPDFillingTimeline],
               scd.[Remarks] AS 'Comments',
               mm.MileStoneId,
               mm.MileStoneName AS 'Milestone',
               mm.Category AS 'Category',
               sc.[BaseLineDate],
               sc.[ActualDate]
        FROM [PMS].[dbo].[StudyCodeDetails] scd
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudyCodeToMileStone] sc ON scd.StudyCodeId = sc.StudyCodeId
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MileStoneMaster] mm ON sc.MileStoneId = mm.MileStoneId
        INNER JOIN dbo.ProductMaster pm ON scd.ProductId = pm.ProductId
        INNER JOIN dbo.TherapyMaster tm ON tm.TherapyId = scd.TherapyId
        INNER JOIN dbo.DosageMaster dm ON dm.DosageId = scd.DosageId
        INNER JOIN dbo.CountryMaster cn ON cn.CountryId = scd.CountryId
        INNER JOIN dbo.[User_Dtls] ud ON ud.Pk_ID = scd.RnDProjManagerId
        INNER JOIN dbo.[User_Dtls] udd ON udd.Pk_ID = scd.ProjectManagerId
        INNER JOIN dbo.CroMaster crm ON crm.CroId = scd.CRO
        INNER JOIN dbo.DesignMaster dsm ON dsm.DesignId = scd.DesignId
        INNER JOIN dbo.DesignTagMaster dtm ON dtm.DesignTagId = scd.DesignTagId
        INNER JOIN dbo.StudyTypeMaster stm ON stm.StudyTypeId = scd.StudyTypeId
        INNER JOIN dbo.ConditionMaster com ON com.ConditionId = scd.Condition
        WHERE scd.StudyCodeId IN (
                SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER)
                FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@StudyCodeId, ',')
            )
            AND mm.[AdditionalPayment] = 0
        ORDER BY mm.MileStoneId
    ) AS X
    GROUP BY X.[IsActive]
             --scd.[StudyCodeId]
             ,
             X.[StudyCode],
             X.[ProductName],
             X.[TherapyName],
             X.[Dosage],
             X.[StudyType],
             X.[Condition],
             X.[CountryName],
             X.[CRO],
             X.[Design],
             X.[DesignTag],
             X.[RnD ProjManager],
             X.[Project Manager],
             X.[IPDFillingTimeline],
             X.[Comments],
             X.[MileStoneId],
             X.[Milestone],
             X.[Category],
             X.[BaseLineDate],
             X.[ActualDate]

END
```

Comment: Your order by is useless,that's why the server would not allow you to do this.

Comment: @Loser but i am using it as to sort the desired output using milestone id

Comment: You are using it to sort a set returned by a subquery, from which you select later. Use order by on the whole query.

Comment: If you want to sort your data, you should put it after the `group by` and before the `end`

Comment: @PawełKucharski I want to get a sorted record and then group them by studycode

Comment: SQL works with sets. The order of elements in a set is not importatnt, therefore your 'order by' is meaningless. The order can be important only when the set in transformed to the result set. So, the 'order by' may be used only in the outter most select statement.

Comment: The *only* place which controls the order in which results are returned by a query are an `ORDER BY` clause on the *outermost* query. Any other occurrences of `ORDER BY` are only used to define *other* parts of a query, such as to make `TOP` deterministic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  
what if i want to sort it before grouping it ???

Comment: @user3682373 - in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. In particular, one way in which the system *may* perform grouping is to sort the data itself, based on its own criteria. Even if there was a way (there isn't) to ask for sorting before grouping, the `GROUP BY` operation could easily obliterate that sorting by performing a different sort.

Comment: @ElderSmash - you're wrong. See "Logical Processing order for [SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)". `GROUP BY` is about in the middle. `ORDER BY` is almost the last possible operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetALLStudyCodedtls]
(
    @StudyCodeId VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS

BEGIN

    SELECT X.[IsActive]
           --scd.[StudyCodeId]
           ,
           X.[StudyCode],
           X.[ProductName],
           X.[TherapyName],
           X.[Dosage],
           X.[StudyType],
           X.[Condition],
           X.[CountryName],
           X.[CRO],
           X.[Design],
           X.[DesignTag],
           X.[RnD ProjManager],
           X.[Project Manager],
           X.[IPDFillingTimeline],
           X.[Comments],
           X.[MileStoneId],
           X.[Milestone],
           X.[Category],
           X.[BaseLineDate],
           X.[ActualDate]
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.IsActive,
               t1.[StudyCode],
               t2.ProductName,
               t2.TherapyName,
               t2.Dosage,
               t2.StudyType,
               t2.Condition,
               t2.CountryName,
               t2.CRO,
               t2.Design,
               t2.DesignTag,
               t2.[user_name] AS 'RnD ProjManager',
               t2.[user_name] AS 'Project Manager',
               t1.[IPDFillingTimeline],
               scd.[Remarks] AS 'Comments',
               t2.MileStoneId,
               t2.MileStoneName AS 'Milestone',
               t2.Category AS 'Category',
               t1.[BaseLineDate],
               t1.[ActualDate]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT sc.IsActive,
                   scd.[StudyCode],              
                   scd.[IPDFillingTimeline],
                   scd.[Remarks] AS 'Comments',              
                   sc.[BaseLineDate],
                   sc.[ActualDate],
                   sc.MileStoneId
             FROM [PMS].[dbo].[StudyCodeDetails] scd
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudyCodeToMileStone] sc 
                 ON scd.StudyCodeId = sc.StudyCodeId
        ) AS t1
        CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT pm.ProductName,
                           tm.TherapyName,
                           dm.Dosage,
                           stm.StudyType,
                           com.Condition,
                           cn.CountryName,
                           crm.CRO,
                           dsm.Design,
                           dtm.DesignTag,
                           ud.[user_name] AS 'RnD ProjManager',
                           udd.[user_name] AS 'Project Manager',               
                           mm.MileStoneId,
                           mm.MileStoneName AS 'Milestone',
                           mm.Category AS 'Category',
                    FROM [dbo].[MileStoneMaster] mm 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductMaster pm ON scd.ProductId = pm.ProductId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.TherapyMaster tm ON tm.TherapyId = scd.TherapyId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.DosageMaster dm ON dm.DosageId = scd.DosageId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.CountryMaster cn ON cn.CountryId = scd.CountryId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.[User_Dtls] ud ON ud.Pk_ID = scd.RnDProjManagerId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.[User_Dtls] udd ON udd.Pk_ID = scd.ProjectManagerId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.CroMaster crm ON crm.CroId = scd.CRO
                    INNER JOIN dbo.DesignMaster dsm ON dsm.DesignId = scd.DesignId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.DesignTagMaster dtm ON dtm.DesignTagId = scd.DesignTagId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.StudyTypeMaster stm ON stm.StudyTypeId = scd.StudyTypeId
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ConditionMaster com ON com.ConditionId = scd.Condition
                    WHERE scd.StudyCodeId IN (
                            SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER)
                            FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@StudyCodeId, ',')
                        )
                    AND mm.[AdditionalPayment] = 0
                    AND mm.MileStoneId = t1.MileStoneId
                    ORDER BY mm.MileStoneId
        ) AS t2         
    ) AS X
    GROUP BY X.[IsActive]
             --scd.[StudyCodeId]
             ,
             X.[StudyCode],
             X.[ProductName],
             X.[TherapyName],
             X.[Dosage],
             X.[StudyType],
             X.[Condition],
             X.[CountryName],
             X.[CRO],
             X.[Design],
             X.[DesignTag],
             X.[RnD ProjManager],
             X.[Project Manager],
             X.[IPDFillingTimeline],
             X.[Comments],
             X.[MileStoneId],
             X.[Milestone],
             X.[Category],
             X.[BaseLineDate],
             X.[ActualDate]

END
```